# Stop all running Thread running in the Activity

Tags: android

*I want to stop all the thread running in my activity. in that  there can be 2-3 thread running so can i stop that all when i go back. 
is there any idea???

Answer (score 4):

use: 
**System.exit(0);**
When you want to exit from the application.
System.exit(0); will stop all the running threads.

Comment: but i am only want to go back to previous activity not to exit the application

Comment: problem is that when i go other activity then the thread running on previous Activity, producing problem for my that acitivity

Answer (score 1):

Try using [threadpool](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow%28%29) create and manage all your threads, to kill them all, call shutdownNow() in your Activity.onDestroy(). A note from the API: "any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate". hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

If your thread runs on a loop, you can manually break out from the loop. As you mentioned, when you go to the other activity, you can perhaps set a boolean and within the threads that you want to stop, you can continually check for the value of the boolean. If the boolean meets the criteria, then you break from the loop.